# How can I have downvoted a question I never visited?

Tags: discussion, support

I got a notification that I lost 1 rep for downvoting an answer, [PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class AppModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423835/php-fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-class-appmodel/). You can see that it shows here:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Problem is, I've never seen this question before. Going through my browser history and logs, I never even visited that page until I noticed the -1. Not to mention that I generally only lurk in the C# tag, and RARELY venture outside that.

I thought maybe I left my computer unlocked and a co-worker did it, but my office door was still locked (I have the only key to the deadbolt). Also, it's the only activity that I don't recognize. So, how can I downvote a question I've never seen?

Comment: Have you seen the _answer_ you downvoted before? Since you lost rep for it, it would have to be an answer. I would think a logical reason is you saw the particular answer in a review queue and downvoted it. That, or you flagged it (I believe VLQ does this) and the flag gave an automatic downvote. I know at least one flag type does this. Either way, review queue is a reasonable explanation for never having been to the specific page.

Comment: @Kendra: I've not looked at the review queue in ages.

Comment: In that case the review queue took revenge...

Comment: Yeah, I just thought to look at your review history- You haven't hit those since May, so I'd say it's not that. It's hard to say, then.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks Do you have a dog or a cat, which may laid on your keyboard ? Or maybe a little brother :)?

Comment: @Rizier123: if only i could blame a cat. :(

Comment: @mycodesucks do you have the SE mobile app? maybe a "pocket-downvote"?

Comment: @MyCodeSucks And now you still ask, why every programmer has at least 7 cats :)?!

Comment: Don't feel bad about a downvote on a PHP answer. If you do find out that your cat did it, buy it some treats.

Comment: Jokes aside, no cat, brother, co-worker, mobile app pocket/butt voting. Just a seemingly random downvote.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks that is very peculiar. because at his point I'd say it's either a bug , you stayed logged on somewhere, or your account got compromised (for a downvote... which brings up other questions )

Comment: This is very peculiar indeed - makes me want to check my history, just in case it may have happened before.

Comment: Is there a way for a moderator to reverse it? I may have only lost 1 rep, but some poor guy lost more. I can't reverse it since it's been more than 5 hours, unless it gets edited.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks I think you can edit the post and then remove your downvote, no harm will be done

Comment: @MyCodeSucks, please, change your password. If this was another person at another machine, it can break more things next time.

Comment: @Kendra: that post was never subject of a review.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks: Moderators cannot reverse individual votes, no.

Comment: Now, you have taken revenge. Stackoverflow users know it. So, they charged you to bear with 5 * 19 - 1 = 94 more same cases. Good luck

Comment: @Rizier123 - we only have 4 cats, but we *do* have 25 goats. :-)

Comment: [Did you happen to trip over a cat after losing your daughter at the park?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/287256)

Comment: @MyCodeSucks Have you ever visited [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20593337/when-i-resize-my-form-to-full-screen-my-controls-are-still-on-old-position#20593337)? It's just two numbers away from the question ID your account downvoted, and an answer there was also removed.

Answer (score 46):

All signs point to your account having downvoted that answer. The post was never in a review queue so you must've loaded the page and clicked the downvote button, perhaps by accident.

I don't see any suspicious activity on your account either; no additional logins (last time you used an OpenID login was almost 2 weeks ago), no extra IP addresses showing up, nothing.

We'll be happy to reset your login sessions if you are worried someone got access to your account somewhere, you'll have to log in again when we do this (although why they'd only downvote one random post and not take advantage in more creative ways is anyone's guess). I can also edit that post for you if you want to undo the vote; an edit will unlock it.

Comment: *I can also edit that post for you if you want to undo the vote; an edit will unlock it.*---infact you should so that OP may reverse the downvote... OP has also stated the same in one of the comment.

Comment: So either cat, or aliens.

Comment: @TLama: no, [a butterfly](https://xkcd.com/378/). Good ole' `C-x M-c M-butterfly`.

Comment: Maybe a single digit got switched somewhere and the downvote was attributed to the wrong post. We need a random number switcher to see if somehow the numbers could be rearranged to point to a c# question that the user visited o_0

Comment: @humble.rumble that would make sense only if the post ID was [four](http://xkcd.com/221/).

Comment: @TLama - ...or goats. You can blame goats for pretty much anything. :-) One of our yearlings got out of the pasture the other week, and had such a good time (she bawled like a baby because she was separated from the herd and couldn't figure out how to get back *in* to the pasture :-) that three of her compadres decided to go for a little saunter of their own. Fortunately one of our daughters discovered they had escaped before they got into trouble. And now *that* particular fence section is reinforced like Fort Knox..! :-)

Comment: If the OP really didn't visit that question/answer, then what they've experienced *could* potentially point to a bug deep inside the SE engine.

Comment: @cybermonkey: we'd have seen this happen much more; it is *more likely* the OP didn't realise they had visited that page and voted. Too many people use the site daily for any such bug to remain so rarely noticed.

Comment: Without a clear path to reproduce, there's no sense in wasting time on such speculation, @cybermonkey. I checked the logs for that day - the OP visited two questions (the referer was Google for both, so opening search results) and within about 15 seconds downvoted an answer to one of them. There's nothing odd or suspicious about the requests, no apparent shared IPs... It is most likely a misclick; if a bug, it is one that would be exceedingly difficult to detect or reproduce.

Comment: I don't know. I'm still not sure. I'm usually fairly cautious with my answer voting, but I can concede it may have been a misclick on a question that I visited but moved away from because I realized i was in the wrong spot.