# My votes were suddenly undownvoted and the posts they were on still exist -- what happened?

Tags: support, voting, serial-voting

I downvoted (as well as upvoted) many questions fairly quickly, and woke up to find all my downvotes had been reversed.

[image: screenshot of 'undownvoted' reputation changes]

Could someone please explain why this is a feature, and what happened? All of the posts still exist; these were not deletions, they were blatant reversals.

The question ["undownvoted" rather than "removed" in reputation history?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296276/undownvoted-rather-than-removed-in-reputation-history?lq=1) seems to be similar, but it's regarding "undownvoted" entries on posts that were **deleted**. My question here is pertaining to these entries occuring on posts that still exist and were not deleted.

Comment: There is no such feature. What lead you to believe such a thing exists?

Comment: Did the answer you voted on maybe got deleted?

Comment: Since mods do not know who voted and how (up or down) they cant reverse your vote(s).  The "undownvote" you might see in rep histories is someone reversing their own vote.

Comment: None of the answers got `deleted`  ... I woke up today to find the above occurred on my account, and I am unable to reply to comments --- even on my own thread.

Comment: @rene -  No. This is not a duplicate of that, as the posts still exist.

Comment: Wait a second... you're complaining about gaining 22 rep?

Comment: did you vote on the question or on one of the deleted answers?

Comment: poltergeists - SO is haunted

Comment: @santiago - I am complaining about my votes not counting simply because someone didn't like my vote, so they reversed it.  And I want to know why this is a feature, and why this was done.  I voted for a reason.

Comment: @rene - Please read the revised question above ---  the votes ARE NOT on DELETIONS -- period.

Comment: @SanuelJackson Stop yelling will you, I'm trying to help

Comment: @rene - not yelling, just bringing attention to the key phrases that I have been repeating as I felt that they are just being skimmed right past.  apologies if this offended you, but at least you have the picture now which was the intent.

Comment: I do find it rather suspicious that people are voting to `close` this, considering it is on topic, and a very serious issue.

Comment: For some reason the voting reversal script kicked in. Are that all posts for the same user maybe?

Comment: No, they are different users.  They are common traits between them.  I think maybe 6-10 users total.

Comment: I voted to close because it wasn't clear what you were asking - as you've now added an explanation, I have reversed my vote. It looks like you have been caught serial-voting, could you provide actual links to the questions in, er, question? Ubermeta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141302/248731

Comment: Oh, and this **is** a duplicate; have you actually *read* the answer on [the post @rene linked](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296276/3001761)?

Comment: if it is only for 6 users that explains it. 3 downvotes on the same user within a minute or so is seen as serial voting and will be picked up by the script. I count 21 one reversals in your screenshot...

Comment: @jonrsharpe - The question is completely different.  Multiple questions may have the same solution, but this is much more focused in that the posts in question were never deleted. The votes were directly reversed. This is why I chose Deduplicators answer as the solution on this.

Comment: @rene - That is my thinking as well. -- Just for the record -- I didn't downvote anything here at all.

Comment: *"the posts in question were never deleted. The votes were directly reversed"* - which is exactly the case in the duplicate, too, the subsequent deletion of the posts involved is completely unrelated.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - The thread rene posted was this > http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296276/undownvoted-rather-than-removed-in-reputation-history  <  ...  The one you adjusted for is more relevant, and also closed and on the general Meta site (for history, here is the link jonrsharpe referenced:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141302/who-can-undownvote-besides-me ).

Comment: Yes, I know what rene posted - note that my comment **includes the same link**. You can't close a question as a cross-site dupe. However, both give the **same information** - undownvoted means either an employee or the automated script intervened, *not* a moderator.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - That is why I selected Deduplicators answer below.  Thank you for the link on the other site though.  It is good to have this solution here for those (like me) who tend not to stray too far from SO ;)

Comment: The solution **was already here**, and you would have trivially found it if you'd spend the time searching for the word *"undownvoted"* instead of mouthing off about moderators and the point of voting.

Comment: @rene 21-and-a-half items. Just round up the half and you'll get to 22.

Comment: FLAGGED FOR MODERATOR -- This is not a duplicate question.  It was closed by common mistake as duplicate due to similarities in another linked question.  I have edited with screenshot, and encircled the alleged duplicate with an explanation detailing how this question is not the same.  The proposed `duplicate` is asking about posts that were deleted, while mine is the opposite -- I am asking about posts that are still active.

Comment: The key here --- in my case, the posts STILL EXIST --- can't stress that enough.  In the alleged "duplicate" -- this is OPPOSITE --- the posts DO NOT EXIST.  Thats a pretty clear and significant difference to warrant this is a NEW question.  I can understand how this may be confused as it is a similar topic --  `undownvoted`, however the similarity ends there.

Comment: The author of the dupe asked their question with the information available to them at the time. They assumed that the posts having subsequently been deleted was relevant. It wasn't. The same "undownvoted" behaviour would have been experienced either way (the undownvoted predates the answers being deleted -- but the original author did not check the site at an appropriate time to see that). That you've accepted an answer saying the same thing as the accepted answer on the dupe is a strong indication that it *is* a dupe.

Comment: @TZHX - It also occurred from the question on two downvotes, in which case the liklihood of the system automatically undownvoting for downvote spam is approaching absolute zero. So either the author lied about only two downvotes, or the system was broken, or there is another reason this happened.  In any case, the question still does not equal this question.

Comment: I have requested that moderators who feel this question is such a duplicate, to DELETE this question since there is no sense in having the same question over and over ....  and if not, then remove the `duplicate of` flag, and post that as an ANSWER or edit one of the answers to include it as a reference due to it being similar but NOT identical in nature.

Comment: Well, there was also the down vote on the question (that makes it three against the same user). Possibly a fourth on their other question. Since downvotes on questions have no rep consequences to voter it's not as easy to track. I don't believe the author of the dupe lied. He is an arsehole, certainly, but he's got better avenues to express that than meta.

Comment: @TZHX - Wrong. Downvoting does have rep consequences to the voter in the form of -1 per downvote. Given the question, there is no evidence to suggest the accuracy of your comment here, aside from you being the author of the question being referred to.  That being said, it is still very different questions, and thus is not a duplicate question.  After some thought, I think it is the way that this is flagged, and the fact it gets closed off referencing something else to make the user 'jump around' to locate information for different questions.

Comment: It really *should* say `possible answer` or `complete answer`, instead of `duplicate` as duplicate implies the string directly to the left of it, and the question data are copies of each other when they are not.  If I sent you a picture of a coffee cup, and a picture of a house,  just because they are both JPG's and the same file size, you would not call them duplicates even though the category is the same.

Comment: I said "downvotes on ***questions***" have no rep penalty for the voter.

Comment: Duplicate, as an adjective -- `exactly like something else, especially through having been copied.`,  as a noun ... `one of two or more identical things.` as a verb ... `make or be an exact copy of.` ---- thus under any use of the word, the `[Duplicate]` flag makes no sense,  unless you are using a different dictionary than the rest of the world. In that case, what other words have you changed the definitions for.  Does `water` mean `air` now ?

Comment: Since all my comments have been about the content of the dupe, I don't see how me being the author of that post isn't enough to give those comments at least a decent level of accuracy.  Given there's basic things about the Stack Exchange model that you don't seem to understand (how duplicates work, why they exist) and you seem like an exceptionally abrasive individual I don't really see anything constructive coming from this thread.

Comment: @TZHX - I believe the correct word is `assertive`.  I never claimed your statement gave no credence, however the issue at hand is comparative analysis between these two questions, not your aforementioned footnotes here as an afterthought to something you (apparently) mis-wrote some time ago.  If you feel that my questioning the abrasive nature of several individuals or the integrity of such (which wasn't an issue until this became a full on debate), then you really have a misguided concept of what `abuse` is. I will post the definition below

Comment: Admittedly, I do reply in-kind and in the exact same manner I am spoken to or treated, so by that pretense if you abuse me, then yes, expect the same back.

Here are the defining points that make up `abuse` > 'use (something) to bad effect or for a bad purpose; misuse.'  and `treat (a person or an animal) with cruelty or violence, especially regularly or repeatedly.` --- the latter is what has been done to me quite often.  Still don't get why it's a surprise or people cry 'boohoo' when I treat them in kind

Comment: Why are you talking about abuse?

Comment: Also, to whoever corrected this -- THANK YOU !!!    And honestly, I am a nice guy, capable of good conversation.  I definitely leave no room for the grey area which admittedly is a flaw, but is also a strength. -- @TZHX - because you did bring it up, however I do not see at any point here where I was abusive or abrasive except in response to similar or in a satirical fashion which could have been misinterpreted. I did not see you updated `abusive` to `abrasive`. in your comment.

Comment: I did not update it. You will notice that comment has not been edited. You really need to work on your reading skills, I think.

Comment: @TZHX - No offense intended, but I do believe either you are trolling me, or you did not read what I wrote. I never stated that you edited that post, on the contrary.  And in addition, the footnotes you a posting about events later discovered/realized, over here, and not on that thread, have zero bearing on the duplicity issue that was in question : Could you clarify where you thought I implied or stated that you updated the other post ?

Comment: `I did not see you updated abusive to abrasive. in your comment. –  Sanuel Jackson 10 mins ago `

Comment: :S ... my bad.  I apologize.  That was my err.  I definitely misread abrasive as abusive, and I did not know (until the `I did not update it` edited note) that the pencil for edited notes shows up for others as well as the author who edited.  I stand corrected on this.

Comment: Any my point in posting here was to try and make you understand that, even though the questions are very slightly different -- they are not different in a way that has any meaning. We don't reserve marking things as duplicates only when the questions are word-for-word identical.

Comment: I've voted to close this again as a duplicate; as TZHX has been saying, the difference that you've highlighted between your question and ["Undownvoted" rather than "removed" in reputation history](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296276) is irrelevant to the thing you're asking about. The root thing is the same in both cases.

Comment: That much I do understand, despite the posting of the definition for the word, that questions that are paraphrased may also have the flag. In this particular instance, I did see enough variation to warrant as a separate question as the referred one was lacking substantially in information and specification surrounding what causes it (in answer) to happen. I personally would not have flagged the question as duplicate. That being said though, it would be ideal if that `[Duplicate]` flag could be something else for questions having similar solutions. As it stands it implies the same Q was asked.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - I appreciate your honesty.   Please stop editing out the explanation of the referred article variations.

Comment: I didn't remove any of your explanation; I took out a bunch of misuse of code formatting and a picture that takes up half the vertical space of your question but has nothing to do with the problem you're asking about. In other words, I cleared away some distractions to make your question more readable.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - That picture has everything to do with regards to the `duplicate` flagging, and you have messed up the formatting with it. The words in `this` are not a misuse of 'code formatting', as everyone knows _code_ in a question is indented, not back-ticked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting, third heading "Inline Code".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a serial-voting-script for detecting and eliminating suspicious voting **patterns** (which *look like* voting on user instead of post, *regardless of intent*), there's no way for eliminating single votes.

Anyway, lowly moderators aren't even trusted with who voted for what, only devs could get there, though even they don't have any acceptable reason, the spare time and the neccessary motivation to manually wade through that data, let alone change it.

Comment: I wish this was the case.  None of those are my threads, or commented on.  I have nothing there to 'up' or 'down' vote.

Comment: I think it was likely an automation issue like you stated.  Voted your answer correct as it is the most likely reason for this problem.  I would hate to think that moderators at any level (except of course dev/admins), have any control over this,  and that the dev/admins themselves do not have the time nor wish to endeavor in such shenanigans.

Comment: Sorry, deleting this question as people are just getting dumb about this.  Thank you for having etiquette. -- wow... can't even delete this, nice.

Comment: Don't worry, downvotes on meta don't have any effect.

Comment: Thank you Deduplicator,  it wasn't the downvotes here so much that I was concerned with, but more the general demeanor this had brought about. Honest to God I did not think that the concept of this being a different question would have gone on for so long, or the amount of negative attention.  I did expect a little due to the nature of the topic, as its pretty standard for `what happened to my` questions on meta to be received negatively.  I am grateful there are some (like yourself), who choose to use the site as it was designed.  Ask a question, get correct answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Deduplicator's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296844/779200), which is almost certainly the right explanation for what has happened here (someone has removed a downvote they previously put on one of your answers), I don't believe a moderator can even *see* who has voted on which posts, much less reverse other people's votes. See, for example, [Martijn Pieters♦'s answer to a recent voting question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296771/779200):

> All signs point to your account having downvoted that answer. ... I
>   can also edit that post for you if you want to undo the vote; an edit
>   will unlock it.

If what you were suggesting was possible, a diamond mod wouldn't need to employ the level of guesswork implied by "all signs point to [this explanation]", and could offer to undo the downvote directly instead of editing the post so that the OP could reverse their own vote.

Comment: I added a screenshot showing the evidence of this activity.  I did not execute these 'undownvotes' .... woke up today to find that.